# (Unit) Testing Akka Streams Kafka

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, akka-stream

I'am currently evaluating Apache Kafka for the use as a middleware in a microservice environment. Not only as a Message Queue but also for aggregating other data sources. Kafka seems to be the perfect fit. The services in majority are based on the Play Framework, so **Akka Stream Kafka** seems to be the natural choice to interact with Kafka.

I prototyped a small App with a *Consumer* and a *Publisher*, communicating via JSON and that was pretty straight forward. But when it comes to unit testing I become a little helpless. Is it possible to run the tests in a lightweight fashion and not with a running Kafka Cluster or an embedded server (check [here](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka))? I also found [this](https://github.com/jpzk/mockedstreams) project which looked promising, but I was not able to test my *Consumer* with it. Isn't that the right tool? I'am a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your question is still relevant, but have you had a look at the [Alpakka Kafka testkit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/1.0-RC1/testing.html)?